# Spring AutoWired in Service Class Exception

Tags: spring, autowired

I will be mad soon guys :)
I have a basic Service class look likes

```
@Service
public class CategoryService {


@Autowired
@Qualifier("categoryDaoImp")
CategoryDaoImp categoryDaoImp;

@PostConstruct
public void asdasdas()
{
    System.out.println("Yaratıldı");

}


public CategoryService()
{
    System.out.println("Bla Bla");

}
```

}

Here is the My Exception ..

```
Error creating bean with name 'categoryService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.iu.eblood.daoImp.CategoryDaoImp com.iu.eblood.serviceImp.CategoryService.categoryDaoImp; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.iu.eblood.daoImp.CategoryDaoImp] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=categoryDaoImp)}
```

I am sure CategoryDaoImp class was created.. Because I saw in the context and debug mode 
Created Class list are

```
 org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,
 org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,
 org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,
 org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,
 org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,
 categorydaoimp,
 categoryService,
 org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,
 DB2DataSource
 ,sessionFactory,
hibernateTemplate,
 org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,
 org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,
 org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,
 org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,
 DB2TransactionManager
```

Comment: The class listing shows a bean named "categorydaoimp", but you try to autowire a bean named "categoryDaoImp".

Comment: I fixed it  but I am taking same error

Comment: Show us the bean definition and source code of CategoryDaoImp

Comment: @Repository("categorydaoimp")
public class CategoryDaoImp extends GenericDao<Category, Long> {

 public CategoryDaoImp() {
  super(Category.class);
 }
 

}

Comment: So you didn't change it to @Repository("categoryDaoImp").

Comment: No I changed @Qualifier as @Qualifier("categorydaoimp")in service class

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the bean name and type (`CategoryDaoImp`) I guess there is an `CategoryDao` interface. Try with this:

```
@Autowired
CategoryDao categoryDao;
```

The problem is a `@Transactional` annotation that (guessing again) you have placed on `CategoryDao`.

Comment: I have a abstract class GenericDao and it has some method for hibernate CRUD operations  and I annotated it with @Transactional (as class)